# ApacheMQ 5.18.2 resource adapter on Wildfly 29 not working

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, jakarta-migration, resource-adapter

I'm trying to use the resource adapter for Apache ActiveMQ 5.18.2 on a wildfly 29 application server. However, it seems to not be working, throwing errors when I deploy the rar-file.

Looking at the ra.xml file, it contains a lot of references to javax-packages. If I update everything in ra.xml to jakarta, it still gives me an error when deploying the rar-file:

Is the 5.18.2 resource adapter suppose work with a jakarta application server?

Error:

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/activemq/ra/ActiveMQResourceAdapter (Module "deployment.activemq-rar.rar" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/apache/activemq/ra/MessageResourceAdapter (Module "deployment.activemq-rar.rar" from Service Module Loader): javax/resource/spi/ResourceAdapter

(using Artemis is not an option).

Answer (score 1):

We finally solved it by both building the current main branch from apache and updating the ra.xml (jakarta migration and schema update).